# Replacing everything with a backslash till next white space

Tags: python, regex

As part of preprocessing my data, I want to be able to replace anything that comes with a slash till the occurrence of space with empty string. For example, `\fs24` need to be replaced with empty or `\qc23424` with empty. There could be multiple occurrences of tags with slashes which I want to remove. I have created a "tags to be eradicated" list which I aim to consume in a regular expression to clean the extracted text.

Input String: `This is a string \fs24  and it contains some texts and tags \qc23424. which I want to remove from my string.`

Expected output: `This is a string and it contains some texts and tags. which I want to remove from my string.`

I am using the regular expression based replace function in Python:

```
udpated = re.sub(r'/\fs\d+', '')
```

However, this is not fetching the desired result. Alternately, I have built an eradicate list and replacing that from a loop from top to lower number but this is a performance killer.

Comment: Like this `\\[a-z]+\d+` you mean?

Comment: `re.sub` takes three arguments; you aren't passing the string on which you want to perform the substitution. Also, what do you think `/` does in the regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that work for you?

```
re.sub(
    r"\\\w+\s*",  # a backslash followed by alphanumerics and optional spacing;
    '',           # replace it with an empty string;
    input_string  # in your input string
)

>>> re.sub(r"\\\w+\s*", "", r"\fs24 hello there")
'hello there'
>>> re.sub(r"\\\w+\s*", "", "hello there")
'hello there'
>>> re.sub(r"\\\w+\s*", "", r"\fs24hello there")
'there'
>>> re.sub(r"\\\w+\s*", "", r"\fs24hello \qc23424 there")
'there'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a 'tag' can also occur at the very beginning of your string, and avoid selecting false positives, maybe you could use:

```
\s?(?<!\S)\\[a-z\d]+
```

And replace with nothing. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hyJL0p/1).

- `\s?` - Optionally match a whitespace character (if a tag is mid-string and therefor preceded by a space);
- `(?<!\S)` - Assert position is not preceded by a non-whitespace character (to allow a position at the start of your input);
- `\\` - A literal backslash.
- `[a-z\d]+` - 1+ (Greedy) Characters as per given class.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `/` doesn't belong in the regular expression at all.

Second, even though you are using a raw string literal, `\` itself has special meaning to the regular expression engine, so you still need to escape it. (Without a raw string literal, you would need `'\\\\fs\\d+'`.) The `\` before `f` is meant to be used literally; the `\` before `d` is part of the character class matching the digits.

Finally, `sub` takes three arguments: the pattern, the replacement text, and the string on which to perform the replacement.

```
>>> re.sub(r'\\fs\d+', '', r"This is a string \fs24 and it contains...")
'This is a string  and it contains...'
```

Answer (score 0):

'\\' matches '\' and 'w+' matches a word until space

```
import re
s = r"""This is a string \fs24 and it contains some texts and tags \qc23424. which I want to remove from my string."""
re.sub(r'\\\w+', '', s)
```

output:

```
'This is a string  and it contains some texts and tags . which I want to remove from my string.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked fine for me:

```
def remover(text, state):
    
    removable = text.split("\\")[1]
    removable = removable.split(" ")[0]
    removable = "\\" + removable + " "
    text = text.replace(removable, "")
    state = True if "\\" in text else False
    return text, state


text = "hello \\I'm new here \\good luck"
state = True
while state:
    text, state = remover(text, state)
print(text)
```